# Is there any condition for groups that have subgroups of order of all divisors of its order?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I want to find the condition of a group $G$ such that for all $a\big||G|$, there exists $H\leq G, |H|=a$.
For instance, If $G=C_n$, then for all $a|n$, $C_a\leq C_n$, so $C_n$ satisfies the condition.

Comment: A sufficient condition is if the group is a product of its Sylow subgroups, but I doubt this is necessary.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thanks!